# Echo not displaying but shows in database

Tags: php, database, variables, echo

I am currently working on an e-commerce site.

When you upload a new product it is all added to the DB and is displayed on the main page (title, price, description, condition etc)

I recently added "stock" to my DB too, and echo $stock on the main page, however it isn't showing up. (You can see the number of stock in the Database) but its not displaying the stock on the main page.

```
 while(list($id, $name, $price, $category, $description, $condition, $stock) = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {   

 echo '<div class="imaging">';
  echo "<img src='../images/"."$id".".jpg' class='imaging'/>" ;
  echo '</div>';

   echo '<div class="box">';

    echo '<div class="title">';
    echo("Title: " . "$name");
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="stock">';
    echo("s: " . "$stock");
    echo '</div>';

    echo '<div class="detail">';
    echo("Detail: " ."$description");
    echo'</div>';
```

^^ just an example of the code, (everything is displayed except for stock)

my sql query is SELECT * FROM ... so it should already be selected.

Thanks for the help

Comment: Probably unrelated but why are you concatenating and then opening new quote marks? Try `var_dump($stock);`

Comment: cargo cult programming detected: `"$id"`, `"$stock"`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

Are the div's etc showing? So you're sure you've updated the code on the server.

Anyways, your code isn't helping that much, if you could show the full SQL too, that would be great!

That the list() doesn't complain is weird too..

You should make sure that the value of stock in db is not null.